# after signing certificate with openssl ca, openssl asn1parse gives error

Tags: openssl, asn.1

I have created `ca.cnf` and create a self-signed certificate,

```
$ openssl req -x509 -key private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -config ca.cnf
```

I sign a request,

```
$ openssl ca -config ca.cnf -in oats.csr
```

Now asn1parse gives an error, if i use offset or not,

```
$ openssl asn1parse -in newcerts/02.pem
Error: offset out of range
```

Any idea?

Please let me know if i must show a part of ca.cnf.

Comment: By default `openssl ca (issue)` writes outpu(s) containing a text-form display of the cert before the actual PEM cert (the block consisting of BEGIN line, base64, END line). `asn1parse` tries to interpret this text-form as part of the data, yielding unparsable garbage. Feed _only_ the PEM block -- or optionally only the base64 part of the PEM block -- to `asn1parse` e.g. `openssl x509 <newcerts/02.pem | openssl asn1parse` or `sed -n '/-BEGIN/,/-END/p' <newcerts/02.pem | openssl asn1parse`. This is not programming or development.

Comment: I opened newcerts/02.pem and indeed! Thanks!